# mPDF - or any other PHP lib for conver HTML + CSS --> PDF

Tags: php, pdf

i am starting to use mPDF PHP library to make simple site which conert few things to HTML, but i am having epic problem with start using it, all the time i get error like:

```
Warning: require_once(D:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/cv/MPDF53/config_cp.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\cv\MPDF53\mpdf.php on line 39

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:/xampp/htdocs/xampp/cv/MPDF53/config_cp.php' (include_path='.;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\xampp\cv\MPDF53\mpdf.php on line 39
```

Line 39 in mpdf.php says:

```
require_once(_MPDF_PATH.'config_cp.php');
```

I dont have anything like config_cp.php in any of my directory and i try more version of mPDF with same problem. So in general yea i know its not working because of missing file but WHY? And HOW can i fix it? I try to manualy make blanked file with that name and didnt help.

I am testing it on localhost and on FTP as well, on both same problem and it cant be because of bad permissions.

Any idea how can i fix it? Or do you have experience with any other HTML + CSS -> PDF lib?

Comment: download that file here https://github.com/viliam-husar/mPDF/blob/master/config_cp.php

Answer (score 1):

Upon installing the module (v7.x-2.1) and MPDF library (v5.6), I got a WSOD at /admin/config/user-interface/mpdf

Checking my logs I saw "Warning: require_once(/var/www/vhosts/sitename.com/httpdocs/sites/all/libraries/mpdf/config_cp.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in require_once() (line 39 of /var/www/vhosts/sitename.com/httpdocs/sites/all/libraries/mpdf/mpdf.php)."

Sure enough, line 39 of mpdf.php calls for a file called "config_cp.php" which was not in the library package. After finding this file online and adding it to the library folder, the config page loaded properly.

You can get a copy of config_cp.php here:
http://www.phpkode.com/source/p/mpdf/MPDF53/config_cp.php

Answer (score 0):

I think you have download the wrong or upgraded version mPDF package which just contains the updated or new files.

In order to use this module, Download the Full installation mPDF package direct from their website www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/download version 5.4 or higher which contain the entire library file package also this "config_cp.php" file . This is mentioned in the module Readme.txt file.

Click to download latest mPDF library